# Android studio - adb problems (stops working after some time)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

**Problem**

- boot computer, start android studio => everything works for a while
- suddenly my usb device is not showing up again (nor anything else) in the "Select Deployment Target" Dialog; it says "Initializing ADB" and then shows an empty window

**What I tried already**

- disconnect usb devices
- kill all "adb.exe" processes
- then try to restart adb with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` or I just click the "Android Monitor" window in Android studio (which initialises adb as well) or I click start and wait until the "Select Deployment Target" Dialog finishes initialising adb => either nothing happens (for the command line commands) or adb does not start and nothing happens (empty dialog, the default adb could not be started dialog)

And I tried all combinations, killing, disconnecting and so on. A reboot of the computer helps and everything works again for some time...

**Development Environment**

- Windows 7 computer
- newest sdk
- newest stable android studio
- real device

I've installed the android SDK in a folder + I've set up android studio to use this SDK (path is defined in "Appearence & Behaviour > SystemSettings > Android SDK > Android SDK Location)

*Any ideas what I could do? Maybe something is broken? In general everything works but every now and then adb stops working. In the last months the number of this incidents increased a lot, it was a very rare thing a few months ago*

Comment: Your adb versions are different from each other what you installed  and what you have in android sdk folder -> platform tools->  adb.

Comment: I've added following to my post: "I've installed the android SDK in a folder + I've set up android studio to use this SDK (path is defined in "Appearence & Behaviour > SystemSettings > Android SDK > Android SDK Location)" That's what you're referring, correct? So this is not the case for me

Comment: What if you don't start AS, just plug a smartphone to the PC, then connect to adb via command prompt? Will it lose connection after some time?

Comment: cd to your sdk/platform-tools and then this adb kill-server command

Comment: @CoolMind never happened yet..

Comment: @muditsen1234 that's what I do when I try to kill and restart the adb server